# Enabling an already enabled timer

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have a program that functions as a monitor software for my arduino motion detector and I am requesting sensor data through timer. I have made it so the alarm has to be reset explicitly through a button. My question is therefore; do I want to set the enabling of the timer to false, before changing the detection variable, then enabling it?

tl;dr What happens when you enable an already enabled timer? Is it bad or does it just reset?

Comment: Why don't you try it first and then come here?

Comment: "*What happens when you enable an already enabled timer?*" Nothing. *does it reset?* No.

Comment: What kind of timer? There's a forms timer, a systems timer, a threading timer... all of which have excellent documentation that cover questions like this. Also, it's very easily tested.

Comment: @nikhilvartak, itsme86, Actually I did. I was just wondering if it was less than optimal or not. Just because both do the same thing doesn't mean they're meant to be used that way or otherwise. I am not asking if I CAN enable ian enabled timer. I am asking WHAT HAPPENS if, on a deeper level than just "it seems to work". If that triggers you - then I am truly sorry. Thanks though.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you.

Comment: @domin8 You still haven't stated what kind of timer you're talking about.

Comment: @itsme86 WinForms timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the Enabled property on an instance of System.Windows.Forms.Timer does not reset the timer.  The state of the timer only changes if the value that you assign to Enabled is different to the current value, ie: currently False and you set it to True or currently True and you set it to False.

Behind the scenes, the first thing that happens is an exclusive lock is aquired on the object.  In .Net 2 and 3.5 this is done through the use of a [Lock Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx).  In .Net 4 this is done using the [Monitor Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or more specifically the Monitor.Enter() method.  Once a lock has been successfully aquired the check is performed to determine if the newly assigned value of Enabled is different to the current value.

This information was gained by decompiling the System.Windows.Forms.dll assembly.  I would have posted the code snippet but I am unsure as to the legality of doing so.

In summary, it is ok to set the timer to Enabled = true when it is already enabled however you do need to be aware that exclusive aquisition of the object is being requested every time you do so.

Comment: Great answer. Much appreciated.